# Developing an eclipse plugin to deploy on my server

Tags: eclipse, plugins, project, deploying

How can we create an eclipse popmenu plugin (which is similar to Google App engine SDK). i.e. If I have created a project, when I clicked on the plugin menu, it should be able to deploy to my tomcat/webapps folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? The [Eclipse Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) already provides that functionality.

For deploying to a remote server you may choose the Export / Web / WAR file option from your projects context menu as shown below and export it directly to the remotly mounted tomcat/webapps folder as shown below.

[image: Export Web Archive]

If mounting the remote filesystem is not possible you will probably have to rely to ant or maven tasks to publish your war file.

Comment: I am having my server on a virtual machine, i want to locally develop application and deploy it to server remotely.

Comment: Can i write a plugin for eclipse so that it can be done automatically.